# How to lock a Stream?

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream

I have 2 threads:

Thread 1 is writing to a stream.

And thread 2 is reading from that stream.

How can i, in thread 2, lock the thread 1 from writing to it? So that i can read the from the stream?

```
MemoryStream outputStream= new MemoryStream();
```

Thread 1:

```
stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileToSend);
compressor.CompressionMethod = SevenZip.CompressionMethod.Lzma2;
compressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Fast;

compressor.CompressStream(stream, outputStream);
```

I want to read from the outputstream in the thread 2. 
I have tried using `lock(outputStream)` and `outputStream.Lock(0,outputStream.Lengh)` and both don't stop thread 1 from writing to it.

**i am using sevenZipSharp**

Comment: Have you tried closing the stream, when you finished writing to it. Thread 1 may still be holding the handle.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this library is thread-safe enough when writing & reading occured simultaneously. When you do some writing, there is no guarantee that another thread will be able to read it instantly, before the writer is closed. I advise you to perform writing & reading serially. (write -> close -> read -> close -> etc)

Comment: That is the thing, i don't want to close it. The compressor will take about 30 sec to do its thing. I want to, while he is doing his thing to stop him from writing to `outputstream` and let me read from it.

Comment: do you intend to get compressed or uncompressed data?

Comment: Well, that defits the purpose. I don't want to close it. Is there no code to block a stream from being accessed ?

Comment: I intend to get the outputStream wich is compressed data.Put it in a byte[] and send to network.

Comment: What that outputStream is? I think you can just switch it with networkStream directly. `compressor.CompressStream(stream, networkStream);`

Comment: OutputStream is a `MemoryStream`. And i cannot use `NetworkStream` directly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328068/7zip-compress-network-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing reading & writing simultaneously, I advise you to write the compressed stream directly to the network.

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible for sevenZipSharp library to write directly into NetworkStream.

As alternative, you can use [DeflateStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) instead. It's able to write to NetworkStream directly. It's already included out-of-the-box within .NET Framework (System.dll).

```
client.Connect(targetHost, port);
var networkStreamRaw = client.GetStream();
var networkStreamCompressed = new DeflateStream(networkStreamRaw, CompressionMode.Compress);
{
    networkStreamCompressed.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
}
```

I have tested the code above with 1MB of data, and successfully get reduced-size (compressed) from the receiver.

```
1048576 bytes of raw-data sent.
1033 bytes of compressed-data received.
```

My test code is available here http://pastebin.com/X0SYjYD7

EDIT: as for decompressing it back, you can get that from `new DeflateStream(streamReadingCompressedData, CompressionMode.Decompress)`.

Comment: So with this i wont be using SevenZipSharp anymore. Is this compression method has fast has 7zipS ? Can you tell me the disadvantages?

Comment: It should be faster because you don't need a temporary MemoryStream to hold the temporary compressed data. Actually deflate is commonly used as compression within the network, because it can do compression on-the-fly, no need to wait until Close() is called.

Comment: I'm not sure about the disadvantage. Probably the compression ratio is not very good compared to other slow algorithm.

Comment: Ok. This is (if `deflate` is fast enough) super good. Right now i was using 7zipSharp, and separating a file chunk by chunk compressing each chunk separately and then sending them. It took a lot of steps. Hopefully this is faster.

Comment: In your pastebin you are not using decompression, correct?

Comment: That's why I edited my answer and add the clue for decompression. I have tested that though, the decompressed data is correct (both in length and the actual content)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108639/discussion-between-meme-and-thariq-nugrohotomo).